# Convert this query for eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a Laravel project and trying to convert this query into an eloquent query so I can eager load other relationships.

```
     $restaurants = DB::query('SELECT *,   ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(21.420639) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(-157.805745) ) + sin( radians(21.420639) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM restaurants GROUP BY id HAVING distance < 25 AND ratingsTotal > 0 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5');
```

Any help on how this should look would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model is going to look something like this in Laravel 4. L3 is probably fairly similar but I have little-to-no experience with that.

```
<?php 

class Restaurant extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $table = 'restaurants';

    public function getSomeShit()
    {
        return $this
            ->select('*')
            ->select(DB::raw('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(21.420639) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(-157.805745) ) + sin( radians(21.420639) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'))
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->having('distance', '<', 25)
            ->having('ratingsTotal', '>', 0)
            ->orderBy('distance')
            ->limit(5);
    }
}
```

Remember, that you never put complicated (or any) database logic in the controller, always behind a view.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to cache those radius calculations. Each one can take up 300 to 500ms per calculation. More with order_by clause. I ran this offline and pushed it to a redis cache with zip-distanc-units as the key.