# Check if row exists and if it doesn't insert data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an Eloquent model that is creating new entries into one of my tables. The problem I am having is each time the page runs it is inserting the data over and over. How can I check if that data already exists in that table and if it doesn't exist, then insert that particular data?

```
        foreach($xml as $product) {        

        //var_dump($product); die;

        Order::where('id', '=', $product->reference)->update(
            array(
                'invoice_id' => $product['orderid'],
                'shipped' => $product['shipped'],
                'processed' => $product['processed'],
                'problem' => $product['problem'],
            )
        );

        $tracking = new OrderTrack();
        $tracking->invoice_id = $product['orderid'];
        $tracking->shipper = $product->shipping->shipper;
        $tracking->shipping_method = $product->shipping->shipping_method;
        $tracking->shipping_date = $product->shipping->shipping_date;
        $tracking->shipping_cost = $product->shipping->shipping_cost;
        $tracking->tracking_number = $product->shipping->tracking_number;
        if(!empty($product->shipping->shipping_notes)) {
            $tracking->shipping_notes = $product->shipping->shipping_notes;
        }

        $tracking->save();
        echo'done';
    }
```

The OrderTrack is the section of code I am concerned about. It will create a new entry no matter if the row already exists or not.

**$xml var_dump**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[294]
  public 'order' => 
    array (size=15)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[295]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=7)
              ...
          public 'reference' => string '3053' (length=4)
          public 'reference2' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[310]
              ...
          public 'reference3' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[311]
              ...
          public 'invoice' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[312]
              ...
          public 'order_date' => string '2014-08-14 03:00:06' (length=19)
          public 'billing_date' => string '2014-08-14 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'changed' => string '2014-08-14 13:02:15' (length=19)
          public 'sender' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[313]
              ...
          public 'receiver' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[314]
              ...
          public 'shipping' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[315]
              ...
          public 'products' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[316]
              ...
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[296]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=7)
              ...
          public 'reference' => string '3054' (length=4)
          public 'reference2' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[328]
              ...
          public 'reference3' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[329]
              ...
          public 'invoice' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[330]
              ...
          public 'order_date' => string '2014-08-13 22:00:02' (length=19)
          public 'billing_date' => string '2014-08-14 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'changed' => string '2014-08-14 13:02:20' (length=19)
          public 'sender' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[331]
              ...
          public 'receiver' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[332]
              ...
          public 'shipping' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[333]
              ...
          public 'products' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[334]
              ...
```

Comment: can you edit your code so I can see before $xml?

Comment: It is a converted XML file I var_dumped some of the code and put it in the question. Hope that helps! Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with eloquent at all just php and mysql why you don't select the query from the table and then if the result of query is not null inserting the data by that xml?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing it that way, but there has to be a way to do this in Eloquent. Thanks for looking into though!

Comment: look at this one it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508549/convert-this-query-for-eloquent

Comment: I was able to figure it out I believe I will have to test further. But  changing the start of eloquent insert into $tracking = OrderTrack::firstOrNew(array('invoice_id' => $product['orderid'])); Seemed to solve it.

Comment: I didn't help you solved it! I just encouraged you haha! no problem

Comment: Hey, sometimes it's all it needs. I would have figured that but wouldn't been as quick! When I saw your message I was just thinking there HAD to be a way to do it in Eloquent. Then line by line I looked at the docs and finally found it lol. Thanks again mate!

Comment: :) glad to help! anytime!

Answer (score 0):

Took advantage of `firstOrNew`

```
        $tracking = OrderTrack::firstOrNew(array('invoice_id' => $product['orderid']));

        $tracking->invoice_id = $product['orderid'];

        $tracking->shipper = $product->shipping->shipper;

        $tracking->shipping_method = $product->shipping->shipping_method;

        $tracking->shipping_date = $product->shipping->shipping_date;

        $tracking->shipping_cost = $product->shipping->shipping_cost;

        $tracking->tracking_number = $product->shipping->tracking_number;

        if(!empty($product->shipping->shipping_notes)) {
            $tracking->shipping_notes = $product->shipping->shipping_notes;
        }

        $tracking->save();
```